# Using Python's async/await with PyGObject has made my code synchronous again. Why?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, pygobject

Ok, so here's the beat: I'm developing a [Rhythmbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythmbox) plugin that allows me to copy songs of a playlist from a place to another.

I used `Gio.File.copy_async` to copy the files. Here's what I did at first (the code is actually more complex but stick with me):

```py
files = []
pending = []

def copy_file(file: Gio.File, cancellable: Gio.Cancellable):
    destination_path = ""  # Compute new path

    cancellable.connect(on_cancel)

    self.__file.copy_async(
        Gio.File.new_for_path(destination_path),
        Gio.FileCopyFlags.ALL_METADATA
        | Gio.FileCopyFlags.NOFOLLOW_SYMLINKS
        | Gio.FileCopyFlags.OVERWRITE,
        GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
        cancellable,
        on_progress,
        (),
        on_file_copied,
        None,
    )

def on_cancel():
  ...

def on_progress(self, current_num_bytes: int, total_num_bytes: int):
  ...

def on_file_copied(self, file: Gio.File, res: Gio.AsyncResult, _):
  pending.remove(file)
  
  if len(pending) == 0:
    on_batch_done()
  else
    ...
    
def on_batch_done():
  # Do things after files have been copied
  ...

def copy_files():
  files = []
  cancellable = Gio.Cancallable()
  for file in files:
    copy_file(file, cancellable)
```

At first it was managable but, as code grew more complex, using Gio's `*_async` functions turned the whole thing into a callback hell and made the code more difficult to reason about.

So I decided to use Python's `async/await` to turn callbacks into awaitable coroutines like I'm used to do in Kotlin, now:

```py
class TransfertTask(GObject.Object):
    def __init__(
        self,
        destination: str,
        file: Gio.File,
        cancellable: Gio.Cancellable,
        loop: AbstractEventLoop,
    ):
        ...
        super().__init__()

    def start(self):
        self.__cancellable.connect(self.__on_cancel)

        self.__file.copy_async(
            Gio.File.new_for_path(self.destination),
            Gio.FileCopyFlags.ALL_METADATA
            | Gio.FileCopyFlags.NOFOLLOW_SYMLINKS
            | Gio.FileCopyFlags.OVERWRITE,
            GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
            self.__cancellable,
            self.__on_progress,
            (),
            self.__on_file_copied,
            None,
        )

        return self.__future

    def __on_progress(self, current_num_bytes: int, total_num_bytes: int):
      ...

    def __on_cancel(self):
        self.__future.cancel()

    def __on_file_copied(self, file: Gio.File, res: Gio.AsyncResult, _):
        async def set_future_result():
            self.__future.set_result(self)

        self.__finished = True
        run_coroutine_threadsafe(set_future_result(), self.__loop)
        try:
            file.copy_finish(res)
        except GLib.Error as e:
            self.error = e
  
async def copy_files():
  cancellable = Gio.Cancellable()
  loop = get_running_loop()
  
  await gather(*[
    TransfertTask("...", file, cancellable, loop).start()
    for file in files
  ])
  
def start():
  asyncio.run(copy_files())
```

Thing is, now the code blocks the UI until the files a copied. In order to recover async processing, I have to launch the main coroutine in a seperate thread like so:

```py
def start():
  loop = get_event_loop()
  thr = Thread(target=loop.run_forever)
  thr.daemon = True
  thr.start()
  run_coroutine_threadsafe(copy_files(), loop)
```

I'm very new to asyncio so there's a few things I still don't quite understand. I would expect `await` or event `asyncio.run()` to be blocking until the coroutine has fininshed running. But I couldn't find anywhere on the internet a way to tell Python "*just launch this coroutine and move on, I don't care about the result*". Maybe Python can't do that and I'm still too much thinking like I'm writing Kotlin.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** to expand on [Simon Hawe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14078758/simon-hawe)'s answer, the main problem here is the `asyncio.run()` function I find in most asyncio examples which waits for the awaited coroutines. All the examples you can find on the internet are examples in which **you are in control of the program's entrypoint**, which is not my case here. Within Rhythmbox you must define plugins like so:

```py
from gi.repository import GObject, RB, Peas

class SomePlugin (GObject.Object, Peas.Activatable):
  object = GObject.property(type=GObject.Object)

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  def do_activate(self):
    ... 

  def do_deactivate(self):
    ...
```

Then the class is created and the `do_activate()` method is executed byt Rhythmbox.

As you can see, I have no control over the program's entrypoint so there's no correct place where I can call `asyncio.run()` and it doesn't block the UI.

Maybe it's just me not knowing how to ask search engines, but I'm surprised nobody seemed to have met this use case before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in pure async world, you can just fire of a coroutine without awaiting the result using create_task or ensure_future. An example would be something like

```py
import asyncio

async def dosomething():
    print("Hell")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("world")

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(dosomething())
    for i in range(10):
        print(f"What {i}")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

asyncio.run(main())
```

The important thing is that this only works if you don't combine so to say async and sync code. Or more precisely, the just "blindly" started coroutine must have finished before the function given to asyncio.run has finished. This means the code

```py
import asyncio
from time import sleep

async def dosomething():
    print("Hell")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("world")

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(dosomething())

print("Start")
asyncio.run(main())
print("Stop")

for i in range(10):
    print(f"What {i}")
    sleep(2)
```

will never print world as main finished imediately. So I think you just did the right thing with the new Thread for you problem at hand.

Comment: Well that's exactly my problem. There isn't any "blindly start coroutine" equivalent to `asyncio.run()`? Due to how this process is launched (it a button callback), I can't control how the code is executed. Is there some sort of event loop that runs as long as the plugin exists and to which I can attach the main coroutine to launch?